# Conjunction only with an adverb

Tags: adverbs

I found the expressions like ‘get back to beautiful,’ ‘treat me as happy.’ They make me wonder if it is possible to use only an adverb after the conjunction.

For example, ‘I run as beautifully,’ ‘I run as yesterday’ and ‘I run as in the gym’

Are they correct in grammar?

Comment: What conjunction?

Comment: @BillJ hello conjunction as

Comment: In "as beautifully", "as" is an adverb modifying "beautifully". "As beautifully" is part of a comparative construction which in full might be something like "I run as beautifully as x runs."

Comment: And in "I run as yesterday", "as" is a preposition, and "yesterday" is a comparative clause reduced to the single element "yesterday". In full, it might be "I run as I did yesterday".

Comment: Thank you very much